# Force '2.1' to be different from '2.10' (for SUMIF purposes)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a table. Column A has task numbers, column B has hours. The task numbers have the unfortunate format x.y, where x and y are numbers. This is not a format I have control over. So you can imagine something like:

```
 A         B
Task ID    Hours
2.1        8
2.1        8
3.5        9
2.1        7
1.3        3
```

I want to have a summary table that adds all the hours for each task. Simple:

```
=sumif(A:A, C1, B:B)
```

I have a problem though. If C1 contains the value '2.10' (the 10th subtask of task 2), then, with the above table, I get 23, even though there are no '2.10' values in column A.

I've tried "Format Cell" as text for both column A and cell C1. I tried putting a `'` in front of both C1 and every single value of column A. I've tried having another column that was basically `=A1 & ""` and do the SUMIF on that. I'm at a loss here.

How can I force Excel to consider `2.1` and `2.10` as different values for the SUMIF?

Comment: The actual content of the cell is 2.1 and 2.10 (or '2.1 and '2.10, in both cases, the result is the same)

Comment: This is one of the problems with SUMIF/COUNTIF formulas - it seems like everything is converted to **numeric** where possible, so leading zeroes or insignificant ones like here are effectively ignored, even if they are text values - that's useful in some situations (you don't need to worry about text v number as with VLOOKUP) but in other circumstances it means you get distorted results - other problem areas are +15 digit text strings, strings like 1/1 interpreted as dates and text strings interpreted as scientific numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUMPRODUCT()** will be more helpful to you.  In this example column **A** and cell **C1** are formatted as *Text*

[image]

Comment: This works, as long as all the values in B are numbers. If there's a string (say, a column title), it breaks. I guess I just need to specify B2:B1000 or whatever.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because SUMPRODUCT applied to an entire column is very slow and since you are using labels I suggest:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10=C1)*(B2:B10))
```

But this does require that both C1 and ColumnA are strings (eg entered as `'2.10` or `'2.1`)

Comment: A definite improvement!